# Entering a "Tab" character into Google Docs, when your document has columns

Tags: google-docs

I am working with a two-column document in Google Docs.   The 1st column is a field description. In the 2nd, wider column, I have free text to complete the field information.  In this column, I have setup a left tab stop, so some information lines up near the far right of the column.  However, I cannot enter a "tab" character to get the text to move to this new tab stop.  If I hit the "Tab" key, I jump to the next column entry.

How can I insert a "tab" whitespace character?  Ctrl-Tab/Shift-Tab/Ctrl-i - nothing I've tried to-date works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem..

The "fix" I found to help was to copy a tab from another program or from within the document, and paste it where I want it.

So select a tab character, copy it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>). Now your <kbd>Tab</kbd> key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

`=CHAR(9)` will produce the tab character as a function, so you'd have to concatenate it with your text values, like `=CHAR(9) & "my text"` or `=CONCATENATE(CHAR(9), "my text")`.

But why not just format the column to align-right?

Comment: This question is about Google Docs not about Google Sheets.